# Powershell Webservice Method definition changes

Tags: web-services, deployment, powershell, ssrs-2008

I am using powershell to deploy our SSRS reports, but have come across an issue when deploying multiple reports.

> $uri = "http:///Reportserver2008/reportservice2005.asmx"
>
> $Proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace SSRS.ReportingService2005 -UseDefaultCredential ;
>
> $Proxy | gm "SetItemDataSources"

Which returns a method definition of:

> System.Void SetItemDataSources(string Item, SSRS.ReportingService2005.DataSource[] DataSources)

If I duplicate the code above, the method definition changes the second time it is requested
e.g

> $uri = "http:///Reportserver2008/reportservice2005.asmx"
>
> $Proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace SSRS.ReportingService2005 -UseDefaultCredential ;
>
> $Proxy | gm "SetItemDataSources"
> $Proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace SSRS.ReportingService2005 -UseDefaultCredential ;
>
> $Proxy | gm "SetItemDataSources"

Returns two different method definitions:

> 1. System.Void SetItemDataSources(string Item, SSRS.ReportingService2005.DataSource[] DataSources)
> 2. System.Void SetItemDataSources(string Item, SSRS.ReportingService2005.DataSource[], 0juuvurk, Ve...

Can anyone explain why the definition changes???
I have tried disposing $proxy after first request, Uri does not change

I am thinking I may have to pull out $proxy and only assign it once.
Any insight greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right on with your instincts.  Creating 2nd or 3rd proxies of web services can cause trouble, because the proxies get put into automatically generated namespaces.  So proxying twice actually redoes a lot of work, and creates two very similar looking types in memory.

There are generally two ways to work with this sort of issue:

- Use the -Namespace parameter to force the object into a namespace.
- Use $proxy.GetType().Namespace to find the automatically generated base type

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for that, does help a lot. Explains a few other issues i'm having. Do you know if there is a way of clearing down your session? Several of my scripts randomly stopped working, worked around by opening a another powershell from within powershell, and they would work at that nested level or after a restart. It seems I need a method of keeping my session tidy?!? Thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately, once you load a type in .NET, it can never unload.  New-WebServiceProxy is creating new types, so there's never a possibility for "Remove-WebServiceProxy" or a cleanup.

Like many other Application scope problems, I make use of Start-Job.  That creates a local job in another .EXE.  Start-Job { Test Script } | wait-job | receive-job will let you test again and again from one appdomain.